# Base docker image license

Tags: docker-image

I'm using docker a deployment tool for my product that deployed on-premise.
I'm using alpine as base image, but the problem that alpine and all the other base image include kernel packages that come with GPL license which is not allowed on my company.

How I can fix this issue?

Comment: If the license is not usable in your company, don't use that software.

Comment: you mean don't user docker

Comment: Yeah, or whatever software causes trouble. Keep in mind that even running a Unix based system like Debian or Ubuntu might be impacted